# Aframe load textured obj with custom GLSL shader

Tags: 3d, aframe

I'm working on loading OBJ files with mtl files. It loaded successfully.

Now I have to write my own GLSL shaders for those models I loaded.
But I don't know how to pass those values such as texcoords, vertex normal, etc.
I need these value in order to use them in my own shaders.
Could anyone give me a sample of textured obj file with custom shader or teach how to do this in aframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the OBJ loaded, grab a handle on the mesh:

```
el.addEventListener('object3dset', () => {
  var mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh');
});
```

Then you can apply your own ShaderMaterial:

```
mesh.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    texture: { type: 't', value: 0, texture: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'texture.jpg' ) }
  },

  vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,

  fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
});
```

In vertex shader, you have access to vertex normal. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;
```

> The vertex shader runs first; it receives attributes, calculates / manipulates the position of each individual vertex, and passes additional data (varyings) to the fragment shader.

In the fragment shader, you can sample texture:

```
texture2D(texture, vec2(0, 0));
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial